# How can I get rid of "Outlook Today"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Every time I start Outlook it loads this slow and ridiculously ugly page called "Outlook Today." I'd like it to just default to my Inbox -- is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you go into Tools -> Options, click the Other tab, click Advanced Options, click Browse... where it says "Startup in this folder", you'll get a dialog where you can change the folder Outlook starts in. It's buried quite deep, so here's a picture:

[image: How to disable outlook today]

Comment: Damn you imageshack for losing my screenshot!

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289949) that gives steps for Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007.  (method 2).  This is especially useful for when you place an item in the root of your mailbox by accident.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! This avoids the annoying (~30s) delay when I click this folder by mistake, or collapse the root tree node to look at other sets of folders.

Answer (score 1):

HOW TO DISABLE OUTLOOK TODAY COMPLETELY

This answer is done using Outlook 365

1. Right-click your mailbox and select "Data File Properties..." Highlighted in red in the image. This will open a properties window.

[image]

2. On the properties window, select the "Home Page" tab. Remove the tick from the checkbox "Show home page by default for this folder" Highlighted in red in the image. Press "APPLY" + "OK" now outlook today is disabled completely.

[image]

The "Outlook Today" page is just a web page and can be replaced with another web page if you want to. To do this... using the mouse, highlight the text in the box immediately below the checkbox from step 2 (highlighted blue in the step 2 image) and use CTRL + V to paste in your replacement address from the clipboard (right-click does not work).